# sed include whitespace on new line with text

Tags: sed, syntax

I'm doing the following sed

```
sed -i {/comment : "Blabla" ;/a leakage_power_unit : "1nW";} $file
```

After the line `"comment : "Blabla" ;"` I want to add `"leakage_power_unit : "1nW""` but I want to add some spaces before the string. The result should be `"  leakage_power_unit : "1nW""` but sed is ignoring whitespaces.

I have an alternative which is using the substitute command but the solution is not pretty and this way above is cleaner and more understandable.

So my question is how can I add the spaces with `/a`?

```
sed -i {/comment : "Blabla" ;/a     leakage_power_unit : "1nW";} $file
```

Including empty spaces after "/a" doesn't work

```
sed -i {s/comment : "Blabla" ;/comment : "Blabla" ;\n  leakage_power_unit : "1nW";/g} $file
```

works but the expression can be confusion for others.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace after the `a`,`i` or `c` options are ignored unless `\` is added to prevent them from being ignored.

Taking that into account, the following change to your code should now include the whitespace as well as creating a backup of the original file with `.bak` extension

```
$ sed -i.bak '/comment : "Blabla" ;/a\     leakage_power_unit : "1nW";' $file
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly works depends on which version of `sed` you are using. The syntax of the `a` command in particular is not properly standardized, and so what works on e.g. Linux will fail on a Mac, and sometimes vice versa.

The lack of quoting and the unnecessary use of braces in your examples are somewhat distracting; but try adding a backslash before the first significant space.

```
sed -i '/comment : "Blabla" ;/a \  leakage_power_unit : "1nW";' "$file"
```

Notice also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Works on Linux; demo: https://ideone.com/TA7gNI

On MacOS (or BSD-based Unix platforms generally) you need a backslash and a newline after `a`, and the next line is the text to insert.

For a portable solution, perhaps switch to Awk or Perl instead. Awk doesn't portably support anything like the `-i` option of `sed`, though GNU Awk has an `-i inplace` extension; Perl, of course, is not formally portable at all, but you will find that it is *de facto* available in most places in practice.